# How to Back up conffiles in the same directory without it being read.

Tags: debian, package-management, configuration, debconf

I have seen two extensions being used which doesn't lead to configuration files in /etc/ being read.

The first is -

```
*.conf.backup
```

and the second is

```
*.conf.old
```

Are there any other extensions which you can write so that debconf does not read the backed up conffile ?

Comment: Anything which is not `.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the program reading the configuration files. The usual convention is that configuration files must end in `.conf`, but nothing enforces this. For example `/usr/share/doc/kmod/README` says:

> modprobe doesn't parse configuration files with names not ending in
>   '.alias' or '.conf'. modprobe used to warn about these files.

(And before that it used them without any warning at all.) Or `/usr/share/doc/apache2/NEWS.Debian.gz`:

> Moreover, the configuration mechanism in Debian has changed. All 
>   configurations in sites-enabled and conf-enabled need a ".conf" suffix now.

Some programs use `run-parts`, which again has its own conventions (even multiple ones) for the names of allowed files (see its manual). Others may also implement their custom conventions. Be careful and read the documentation to avoid surprises.